# How to add a functioning image upload button to an existing form?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to upload an image to a pre-existing form however upon form submission I get a 
`SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value` error.

I have managed to get the actual button and file picker on the form to function, however, upon submission it blows up referencing the above error. Any help or resources regarding this issue would be fantastic.

PostController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Post;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $posts = Post::all();

        return view('post.index', compact('posts'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $post = new Post();

        return view('post.create', compact ('post'));
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $data = request()->validate([
            'title' => 'required',
            'body' => 'required',
        ]);

        $post = \App\Post::create($data);

        return redirect('/posts');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Post  $post
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Post $post)
    {
        return view('post.show', compact('post'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Post  $post
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Post $post)
    {
        return view('post.edit', compact('post'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Post  $post
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Post $post)
    {
        $post->update($this->validatedData());

        $this->storeImage($post);

        return redirect('/posts');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Post  $post
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Post $post)
    {
        $post->delete();

        return redirect('/posts');
    }

    private function validatedData()
    {
        return request()->validate([
            'title' => 'required',
            'body' => 'required',
            'image' => 'sometimes|file|image|max:5000',
        ]);
    }

    private function storeImage($post)
    {

        if (request()->has('image')){
            $post->update([
                'image' => request()->image->store('uploads', 'public'),
            ]);

            $image = Image::make(public_path('storage/' . $post->image))->fit(500, 500, null, 'top-left');
            $image->save();
        }
    }
}
```

form

```
<div class="card-body">
                    <form action="/posts/create" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">


                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="title">Title</label>
                            <input name="title" type="text" class="form-control" id="title" aria-describedby="titleHelp" placeholder="Enter Title" autocomplete="off">
                            <small id="titleHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Give your post a title that will describe your post easily</small>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="body">Body</label>
                            <textarea type="text" name="body" cols="30" rows="3" class="form-control" id="body" aria-describedby="bodyHelp" placeholder="Enter Post Body" autocomplete="off"></textarea>
                             <small id="bodyHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Enter as much detail you'd like!</small>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group d-flex flex-column">
                            <label for="image">Post Image</label>
                            <input type="file" name="image" class="py-2">
                        <div>{{ $errors->first('image') }}</div>
                        </div>

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create Post</button>

                        @if (session('message'))

                            <div>
                                {{ session('message') }}
                            </div>
                        @endif

                    </form>
```

Post Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];
}
```

lastly Migration

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreatePostsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->longText('body');
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('posts');
    }
}
```

Comment: (I'm not a Laravel user) I think that for the line `$post = \App\Post::create($data);`, `$data` needs to include the user_id. I'm guessing you could pass it to the `create` call, or override `create` in `\App\Post` & get the `user_id` from the currently logged in user. Unless I'm missing something or that's built-in to laravel already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think by default user_id doesn't have a default value. In your post model,

```html
protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'title', 'body', 'image'];
```

Also in your store function, you have to include user from currently logged in user.

```html
    use App\Post;
    use Auth;
    public function store(Request $request)
        {
            $request->validate([
                'title' => 'required',
                'body' => 'required',
            ]);
            $post = new Post();
            $post->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
            $post->title = $request->title;
            $post->body = $request->body;
            $post->save();
            return redirect('/posts');
        }
```

Comment: I have added the code you mentioned but now get this ```ErrorException
Creating default object from empty value```

Comment: I have edited my answer, you were getting this error because laravel doesn't know what $post is.